# .htaccess block all but one ip NOT WORKING

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am simply just trying to block all ip addresses besides mine to one simple php page. I'm trying to do this through .htaccess but something is going wrong and it block even my ip

```
<Files login.php>  
Require all denied
Require ip MY-IP
</Files>
```

I've even tried doing

```
<Files login.php>  
Require all denied
Require ip 172.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Blocks me from the browser on my VPS

Someone just told me to try

```
<Files login.php>  
Require ip 172.0.0.1
</Files>
```

and it still blocks me from accessing the webpage from the SAME SERVER IM HOSTING THE SITE ON! What the actual f is going on?

Comment: right now I have the following in .htaccess on my VPS                                                                        
`<Files login.php>  
Require all denied
Require ip 172.0.0.1
</Files>`

I go to the browser in the VPS and go to the URL, it for whatever fucking reason is even giving a Forbidden when it shouldn't. What on my ubuntu server or in apache2 do I have to change to fix this absolute bullshit. I'm fuckin pissed

Comment: Rules are evaluated top to bottom, so it hits the deny rule, denies everyone, and that's it.

Comment: ok so I just got rid of that "deny all" and just have `<Files login.php>  
Require ip 172.0.0.1
</Files>` and it still blocks me

Comment: Maybe the IP address the request is coming from, is not actually what you think it is? Have you checked the access log to verify?

Comment: `Require ip 172.0.0.1` - localhost is `127.0.0.1`, not `172.` (and private network ranges start `172.16.`). However, as CBroe has already pointed out, you should check your access log to determine the IP address that Apache is seeing.

Comment: It is giving me a cloudflare ip (since I use cloudflare to protect my site)